# Do Successful User Tags in Comments Get Hyperlinked?

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks, users, formatting

I was reviewing ...

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

re: the format for tagging users who are related to a comment.  I was wondering whether a hyperlink is typically dropped over successful user tags or if it just stays plaintext.  To me this would seem like an obvious solution as it would allow quicker navigation.  Am I doing something wrong, or are user tags in comments really left as plaintext?

Also, when it says the comment you are replying to is automatically notified, how far back in the thread does that go?

I don't want to be annoying and superfluously/unecessarily tag people, but the boilerplate tutorial wasn't exactly clear on whether users several comments back in a thread are also tagged,  or if that just applies to the poster of the most recent comment.

Comment: Yes, usernames in comments are plain text.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer, so I can give you credit?

Comment: @JasonR.Mick Credit doesn't really matter here; it isn't like we get rep for anything on meta.

Comment: I'm liking your comment for irony. ;)